# Authconfig doesn't find all ldap groups

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, sssd

My (soon to be) admin account is in two groups:

```
#  ldapsearch \
> -v \
> -H ldaps://localhost:636 \
> -D "${l_dirmgr}" \
> -w $(cat ${f_dirmgr_passphrase}) \
> -b "ou=groups,${l_basedn}" \
> "member=cn=testuser" \
> dn gidNumber member

dn: cn=wheel,ou=groups,dc=localdomain
gidNumber: 10
member: cn=testuser,ou=users,dc=localdomain

dn: cn=users,ou=groups,dc=localdomain
gidNumber: 100
member: cn=testuser,ou=users,dc=localdomain
```

However, `id` only sees the GID associated in my user's record:

```
# id testuser
uid=20001(testuser) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

How do I dig into `authconfig`/`sssd`/`ldap` to see what it's actually looking for and pulling out? The 389DS access log doesn't show me anything, probably because `authconfig`/`sssd`/whatever isn't updating its cache. I haven't managed to catch an actual lookup in the log.

(I do see in the log that `authconfig`/`sssd`/something is still trying to make anonymous binds, despite my putting a `ldap_default_bind_dn` and `ldap_default_authtok` in sssd.conf.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... `ldap_default_authtok` had an old password in it...

(And, that bruise you see in the middle of my forehead is from me pounding my head on my desk...)

Okay, now with more detail. I created my LDAP instance consistent with my [notes on the subject](https://github.com/dafydd2277/systemAdmin/tree/master/ldap). That included this bit of LDIF:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access
nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access: off
-
replace: nsslapd-require-secure-binds
nsslapd-require-secure-binds: on
```

Since I wasn't allowing anonymous access, I created a service account for PAM to use to connect, along with a service account container:

```
dn: ou=serviceAccounts,${l_basedn}
changetype: add
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: serviceAccounts
description: Container for service accounts. Some will have shell access 
 (objectClass: posixUser), most won't.

dn: cn=svcAuthenticator,ou=serviceAccounts,${l_basedn}
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
cn: svcAuthenticator
sn: svcAuthenticator
userPassword: $(cat ${f_svcAuthenticator_passphrase})
description: Service account to allow PAM/SSS to search the LDAP database.
```

(I need `objectClass: person` to give the account a password. However, `sn` is required attribute of `objectClass: person`. So, I faked it.)

Then, I'd put that passphrase in `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` and `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
sed --in-place=.$(date +%Y%m%d) "/#binddn.*/ a\
binddn cn=svcAuthenticator,ou=serviceAccounts,${l_basedn}" /etc/pam_ldap.conf

sed --in-place "/#bindpw.*/ a\
bindpw $(cat ${f_svcAuthenticator_passphrase})" /etc/pam_ldap.conf

sed --in-place=.$(date +%Y%m%d) "/^ldap_uri.*/ a\
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=svcAuthenticator,ou=serviceAccounts,${l_basedn}" /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sed --in-place "/^ldap_default_bind_dn.*/ a\
ldap_default_authtok = $(cat ${f_svcAuthenticator_passphrase})" /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

That was all well and good, until I changed the contents of `${f_svcAuthenticator_passphrase}` while trying to solve other LDAP issues, and never passed the new value to `pam_ldap.conf` or `sssd.conf`.

Once I remembered to do that, I got good values back out of the `id` command, including full group lists. I also get SUDO privilege lists using `cn=svcSUDO,ou=serviceAccounts,${l_basedn}` and `$(cat ${f_svcSUDO_passphrase})`.

Comment: Please ahev a moer detailed answer to your question. Folk may stumble upon in futur and be happy for a precise answer.